# How do I turn this Swashbuckle .NET 6 operation filter into a generic filter that can handle multiple class types in C# ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, .net-6.0, swashbuckle

I have the following code for operation filter that helps me serialize arrays then sends it to a FromForm binder, how I turned it generic so I can get several class types and pass it over as T type to the following class so I wrote this:

```
public class ArraySettingsOperationFilter<T> where T : IOperationFilter, new()
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (operation.RequestBody != null && operation.RequestBody.Content.TryGetValue("multipart/form-data", out var openApiMediaType))
        {
            var options = new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true };
            var array = new OpenApiArray
         {
        new OpenApiString(JsonSerializer.Serialize(new T(),options)),
         };
            openApiMediaType.Schema.Properties["Competences"].Example = array;
        }
    }
}
```

on startup class i'm getting every class that is marked by an interface and pass them over to operationfilter within Swagger generator settings:

```
var types = typeof(IMarkerInterface)
            .Assembly.GetTypes()
            .Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(IMarkerInterface)) && !t.IsAbstract)
            .Select(t => Activator.CreateInstance(t) as IMarkerInterface).ToList();
```

then:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    foreach (var type in types)
    {
    c.OperationFilter<ArraySettingsOperationFilter<type>>(); //however here error says type is a variable but used like a type.
    }      
});
```

Anyone has a clue how to fix this issue? Or a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `c.OperationFilter<T>` is just a generic extension method that adds `FilterDescriptor`s to `OperationFilterDescriptors` list. So you don't have to rely on that generic method. A few modifications like the below will get you there:

> First change your generic `ArraySettingsOperationFilter` to a class that accepts a type in the constructor

```
public class ArraySettingsOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    private readonly Type type;

    public ArraySettingsOperationFilter(Type type)
    { 
        // you can check this type implements the interface here
        this.type = type;
    }

    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (operation.RequestBody != null && operation.RequestBody.Content.TryGetValue("multipart/form-data", out var openApiMediaType))
        {
            var options = new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true };
            var array = new OpenApiArray
         {
        new OpenApiString(JsonSerializer.Serialize(Activator.CreateInstance(this.type),options)),
         };
            openApiMediaType.Schema.Properties["Competences"].Example = array;
        }
    }
}
```

> Make `FilterDescriptor`s from the marked classes

```
 var filterDescriptors = typeof(IMarkerInterface)
        .Assembly.GetTypes()
        .Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(IMarkerInterface)) && !t.IsAbstract)
        .Select(r => new FilterDescriptor { Type = typeof(ArraySettingsOperationFilter), Arguments = new object[] { r } })
        .ToArray();
// Arguments array will be used for instantiating ArraySettingsOperationFilter
```

> Configure Swaggergen

```
   builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c => c.OperationFilterDescriptors.AddRange(filterDescriptors));
```

**Edit**

You may skip instantiating `ArraySettingsOperationFilter` if your marked types do the same thing.

```
   var filterDescriptors = typeof(IMarkerInterface)
       .Assembly.GetTypes()
       .Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(IMarkerInterface)) && !t.IsAbstract)
       .Select(r => new FilterDescriptor { Type = r } )
       .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

`Activator.CreateInstance(t)` gives you an insatnce, thus `type is a variable but used like a type` is a good hint.

Working with runtime types and generics is sometimes cumbersome. I see two possible solutions here:

You can make a switch expression in the startup and switch on the type of `type`.

The other possibility (which I prefer) is to add a method to `IMarkerInterface` which applies the operation filter `c.OperationFilter<ArraySettingsOperationFilter<type>>()`

So in any implementation of `IMarkerInterface` you add a method like so:

```
ApplyOperationFilter(SwaggerGenOptions c) => c.OperationFilter<ArraySettingsOperationFilter<type>>()
```